# How to change 'on' values that checkboxes return in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

I want to create a new user, this is my view:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/create" method="POST">
                <label>Naam</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" id="password">

                <label>Admin</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="admin" id="admin"><label for="admin">Admin</label>

                <label>Safety Settings</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="watchDashboard" id="watchDashboard"><label for="watchDashboard">Watch Dashboard</label><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="watchBlocks" id="watchBlocks"><label for="watchBlocks">Watch Blocks</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="editBlocks" id="editBlocks"><label for="editBlocks">Edit Blocks</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="watchWastes" id="watchWastes"><label for="watchWastes">Watch Wastes</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="editWastes" id="editWastes"><label for="editWastes">Edit Wastes</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="watchGrondstof" id="watchGrondstof"><label for="watchGrondstof">Watch Grondstof</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="editGrondstof" id="editGrondstof"><label for="editGrondstof">Edit Grondstof</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="manageUsers" id="manageUsers"><label for="manageUsers">Manage Users</label>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            </form>
```

When I hit submit button, I want to get the data in my database:

```
public function create(Request $request){
    $user = new User();
    $user::create(
        $request->all()
    ); 
}
```

When I hit submit I get this error:

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column.

How can I make sure when I do `$request->all()` that the on value is true or 1?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for your User model? It should have the `$fillable` property set so that you can use bulk assignment. Also the syntax you want is `User::create([...])`.

Comment: I just found my mistake! It works when you set the value of each checkbox to 1 (value="1") or 0. Then it returns 1 or 0 when it's checked or not. :)

Comment: you can check the checkbox value like this:

$user['name'] = \Input::has('name') ? true : false;

In your controller.

Comment: @Dawlatzai When adding the value to the html of each checkbox is works :)

Comment: @Yaron you get the input in create method?

Answer (score 3):

How about modifying the data before passing it to the model?

```
public function create(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['watchDashboard'] = $request->watchDashboard ? 1 : 0;
    $data['watchBlocks'] = $request->watchBlocks? 1 : 0;
    ..... (other checkboxes)
    $user = new User();
    $user::create($data); 
}
```

Didn't try it but that was the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the inputs as follows:
after the `<form>` element, I insert hidden inputs, with the same name as the checkbox input, but with the default value - 0 in this case - and for the checkbox add a the value attribute - in this case set to 1. This way, if the checkbox is not checked, the element is set to 0 but if the user checks the input, will override the hidden input's value.